# What are "to" and "update" in the context of npm/node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working with node.js/npm.

My current configuration looks like this: *npm list -g --depth=0*

```
├── bower@1.7.7
├── cordova@6.0.0
├── grunt-cli@0.1.13
├── grunt-sass@1.1.0
├── ionic@1.7.14
├── ios-deploy@1.8.5
├── ios-sim@5.0.6
├── n@2.1.0
├── to@0.2.9
└── update@0.4.2
```

As I am newbie in developing mobile apps using Cordova, Ionic, etc. --> what do "to" and "update" stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're listing top level dependencies for the relative node.js project. `to` and `update` are node.js packages that are likely defined in your package.json file and exist in the top level directory of `./node_modules`.

To better understand what those two specific packages are, read about them here:
The `to` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/to
The `update` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/update